# How gray out a category of propertygrid

Tags: c#, propertygrid

Hey im using a Propertygrid to set the values of a table. Some properties will be reset and set to read only when others are set to some specific value.

This happens in the setter of a property like this:

```
    [CustomSortedCategory("Modes", 2, 4), DescriptionAttribute("..."), ReadOnly(false), DisplayName("Mode")]
    [System.ComponentModel.RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
    public GraphLineFunctions Function
    {
        get
        {
            return function;
        }
        set
        {
            function = value;
            if (function == GraphLineFunctions.TimeDelta || function == GraphLineFunctions.TimeDeltaAll) {
                BasetimeFilter = "";
                PropertyDescriptor descriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.GetType())["BasetimeFilter"];
                ReadOnlyAttribute attrib = (ReadOnlyAttribute)descriptor.Attributes[typeof(ReadOnlyAttribute)];
                FieldInfo isReadOnly = attrib.GetType().GetField("isReadOnly", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                isReadOnly.SetValue(attrib, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want a Category be grayed out too if all properies in this category are set to read only. Does anybody know an easy way to do this?

thank you